# Retrieving SOAP parameters in C#

Tags: c#, soap

I  created test soap service with few simple methods:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CallbackServicePKB
{
[WebService(Description = "CallbackServicePKB", Namespace = "CallbackServicePKB")]
public class ReportCallback : WebService
{

    [WebMethod(Description = "check if report is available for import")]
    public Boolean isAvailable()
    {
        return true;
    }

    [WebMethod(Description = "import report")]
    public String importReport()
    {
        var request =  HttpContext.Current.Request;

        string path = @"c:\temp\soap_request.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path)) {
            string createText = "File created!" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
        }
        string appendText = "New request" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

        return request.Url.OriginalString;
     }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is to write parameters from request in to the file.

Here screenshot how my request looks like:
[image]

My problem is that I don't see these parameters in request object.
[image]

How I can get parameters inside method?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper What do you mean? It is a logo from  Steve Mcconnell's book "Code complete 2"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood (user number is important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your method with parameters which you put into request (the names should be the same) and get values inside method.

`public Boolean importReport(int requestId, String reportURL, String signature){ }`